# Integrated cygwin Terminal in vs code does not work properly

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, cygwin

I'm using Visual Studio Code on Windows and Cygwin as the integrated terminal.
The problem is some commands do not work in this integrated terminal but they do if I open the same terminal separately.

For example, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu81a.png) I try to use the command `opam` from the terminal in vscode. Getting `command not found` as the answer.
Conversely, if I open Cygwin from the desktop and run `opam`, it [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAP5W.png).
The same goes for other commands such as `elpi`.

I have no clue why this happens.

Comment: it seems a problem with the path. You need to use a login shell terminal

Comment: How can I do that? 
I tried to change the path in the setting.json file adding `--login`, but it doesn't work. 
`"path": "C:\\OCaml64\\bin\\bash.exe --login"`

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/using-mingw-and-cygwin-with-visual-cpp-and-open-folder/